# Fetch all the AD Objects having OperatingSystem as attribute

Tags: powershell, c#-4.0, active-directory

I need to retrieve all the computer systems in active directory. I have written the following code :

```
public void ADData()
{
    DataTable ADdt = new DataTable();

    ADdt.Columns.Add("CN");
    ADdt.Columns.Add("DistinguishedName");
    ADdt.Columns.Add("OperatingSystem");
    ADdt.Columns.Add("lastLogonTimestamp");
    ADdt.Columns.Add("PasswordLastSet");

    string lsResult = "";
    DirectoryEntry loDE;

    try
    {
        loDE = new DirectoryEntry(("LDAP://" + ADDomain.Trim()), (ADDomain.Trim() + ("\\" + ADUserName.Trim())), ADPassword.Trim());
        Logger.log("Connected to AD");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(loDE.Name))
        {
            lsResult = loDE.Name;

            DirectorySearcher loDES = new DirectorySearcher(loDE);
            //loDES.Filter = ("&(objectClass=computer)"); 
            loDES.Filter = ("(objectClass=*)");
            loDES.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

            loDES.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");
            loDES.PropertiesToLoad.Add("CN");
            loDES.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
            loDES.PropertiesToLoad.Add("operatingSystem");
            loDES.PropertiesToLoad.Add("lastLogonTimestamp");
            loDES.PropertiesToLoad.Add("pwdLastSet");

            foreach (SearchResult item in loDES.FindAll())
            {
                try
                {
                    tbl_ActiveDirectory tad = new tbl_ActiveDirectory
                    {
                        CN = Convert.ToString(item.Properties["cn"][0].ToString()) ,
                        DistinguishedName = Convert.ToString(item.Properties["distinguishedName"][0]),
                        OperatingSystem = Convert.ToString(item.Properties["operatingSystem"][0]),
                        lastLogonTimestamp = DateTime.FromFileTime(Convert.ToInt64(item.Properties["lastLogonTimestamp"][0])).
                        PasswordLastSet = DateTime.FromFileTime(Convert.ToInt64(item.Properties["pwdLastSet"][0])) 
                    };

                    ADdt.Rows.Add(new string[] { tad.CN, tad.DistinguishedName, tad.OperatingSystem, tad.lastLogonTimestamp.ToString(), tad.PasswordLastSet.ToString() });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.log("Exception getting properties : " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.log("Exception : " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        loDE = null;
    }
}
```

Problem is, it's not returning all the computer objects it should return.

The followig PowerShell command is returning all the required computer objects.

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties Displayname, CN, DNSHostName, DistinguishedName, lastLogon, Created, IPv4Address, lastLogonTimestamp, OperatingSystem, OperatingSystemServicePack, OperatingSystemVersion, whenCreated, whenChanged, Enabled, PasswordLastSet, CanonicalName |
    select Displayname, CN, DNSHostName, DistinguishedName, lastLogon, Created, @{N='lastLogonTimestamp'; E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)}}, OperatingSystem ,PasswordLastSet, CanonicalName
```

I tried using `("(objectClass=computer)")` and `("(!objectClass=user)")` as filter but still no luck.

Basically I want to get all the AD objects which have `operatingSystem` as their attribute.

Also I need to exclude objects from particular OUs. How do I write filter for that?

Comment: Which do you want to use, DirectorySearcher or Get-ADComputer?

Comment: DirectorSearcher

Comment: `(operatingSystem=*)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the actual question "*Problem is, it's not returning all the computer objects it should return*" instead of the workaround:

`loDES.Filter = ("&(objectCategory=computer)");`

Quote under [Filter on objectCategory and objectClass](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx):

> If you have a choice between using objectCategory and objectClass, it is recommended that you use objectCategory. That is because objectCategory is both **single valued** and indexed, while objectClass is **multi-valued** and not indexed